# Android кривой ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

Как сделать так, чтобы ListView был внизу тулбара, а не так криво как на пикче?
И еще вопрос, как убрать эти полоски между элементами ListView? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот xml файл main activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector"
        />



    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Вот код метода onCreate в MainActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this);

    ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. У DrawerLayout должно быть только два ребёнка:

   - Основной контент
   - Левое меню

У вас же их три. Так что вам надо объединить первые два в один. Например оберните их в `LinearLayout`

2. Линии меж элементами списка это `divider`. Убрать их можно... [убрав их](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24653110/3212712):

   ```
   android:divider="@null"
   ```

   и вот эту строку тоже надо убрать: `android:dividerHeight="1dp"`. Или 0 прописать